# SQL Count of frequency returning duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to calculate the loan frequency for every date but when I run my code it just returns the same number for each book. (taken) is the date the book was taken out/loaned

```
SELECT b.isbn,b.title, COUNT((l.taken)) AS 'frequency'
FROM loan l
INNER JOIN books b
GROUP BY title;
```

There isn't a common column in the two tables (books, loan) so I couldn't link them that way.

Can anyone see where this issue is coming from in my code?

I tried the above code and got duplicates.

The desired results are 5, 1,2 as frequency:

```
isbn                title                       COUNT(*) AS 'frequency'
111-2-33-444444-5   Pro JavaFX                  5
222-3-44-555555-6   Oracle Systems              1
333-4-55-666666-7   Expert jQuery               2
```

But i'm getting 5,5,5 as the frequency:

```
isbn                title                       COUNT(*) AS 'frequency'
111-2-33-444444-5   Pro JavaFX                  5
222-3-44-555555-6   Oracle Systems              5
333-4-55-666666-7   Expert jQuery               5
```

Comment: you haven't specified how loan and books relate.  ***you need an `on` clause after your inner join*** to define that relationship also group by both b.ismn and b.title unless title and isbn are ALWAYS the same for the same ISBN/title combination  mysql extends the group by so you don't have to group by all non-aggregrated values in the select.  but it's best not to use it unless you FULLY understand the implications

Comment: "(taken) is the date the book was taken out/loaned". which book?

Answer (score 1):

I could be offbase, but I think you want to count the thing you're grouping by

```
SELECT b.isbn,b.title, COUNT((b.title)) AS 'frequency'
FROM loan l
INNER JOIN books b on b.??? = l.???
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: Missing an "On" clause or how loan/to books relate